# Getting " AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'items' " with pandas.io.json.json_normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas

When trying to normalize a series within a pandas dataframe with the `json_normalize` function i am getting the Error:

```
"AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'items'"
```

Each row of the series contains a nested json, though some rows don't contain all of the attributes, that are present in some of those json' from that series

also there is a field `"timestamp":{"$date":1578411194000}` within those nested json's, which is also present in another column of that same dataframe, giving me an error in another attempt to flatten that other series.

I am assuming the `AttributeError` has something to do with the either not all JSONs containing all the fields or sth. with those `timestamps.json_normalize` did work for some of the other df-columns.

I hope this is enough info. thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The error is because you're probably looping through some level and then instead of the values being another dict, it's a float. You can deal with these different cases by checking things like `hasattr(7.0, 'items')`, except use your variable not `7.0`

Comment: i solved the error by loading the data with json.loads instead of pd.read_json and after that json_normalize worked very well. As for a conditional statement i used something like **normalized_data = json_normalize([x for x in df['column'] if ('key' in x)])** instead of hasattr().

Comment: please answer your own quest. Otherwise this post will be found if someone searches for questions without answers.

Answer (score 3):

It can happen if there are NaN fields which can be solved by using `dropna()` :

```
pd.json_normalize(df.explode("field")["field"]))
=> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'items'

pd.json_normalize(df.explode("field")["field"].dropna())
=> no error
```